# How to Display ads on AMP pages

Tags: php, amp-html

my amp page is working but it not show ads

I add
 `<script async custom-element="amp-ad" src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0/amp-ad-0.1.js"></script>`

and  also creted ad unit as follow

```
<amp-ad width="100vw" height=320  type="adsense"
  data-ad-client="ca-pub-9876543211234567"
  data-ad-slot="1023456789"
  data-auto-format="rspv"
  data-full-width>
  </amp-ad>
```

Answer (score 1):

Follow the official AMPHTML docs on [amp-ads/amp-embed](https://www.ampproject.org/docs/reference/components/amp-ad).

> **Behavior**
>
> Ads are loaded like all other resources in AMP documents, with a
>   special custom element called . No ad network-provided
>   JavaScript is allowed to run inside the AMP document. Instead, the AMP
>   runtime loads an iframe from a different origin (via iframe sandbox)
>   as the AMP document and executes the ad network’s JS inside that
>   iframe sandbox.
>
> The  requires width and height values to be specified
>   according to the rule of its layout type. It requires a type argument
>   that select what ad network is displayed. All data-* attributes on the
>   tag are automatically passed as arguments to the code that eventually
>   renders the ad. What data- attributes are required for a given type of
>   network depends and must be documented with the ad network.

Check the docs for more sample and the supported ad companies.